# True is not true?

Tags: c#, arrays, foreach, boolean, console-application

I'm having an issue where true is not true.  This sounds a little odd, and I think so too, which is why I figured I would get a discussion going about it.

Here is my stripped down code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool[] myValuesBls = new bool[10];

        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (i == 7)
                myValuesBls[i] = true;
            else
                myValuesBls[i] = false;
        }

        bool myIsShouldBeTrue = false;
        foreach (bool valueBl in myValuesBls)
        {
            myIsShouldBeTrue = valueBl;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(myIsShouldBeTrue);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

The values are returning false, which I am pretty sure is impossible.  The seventh item in my array is TRUE.

Comment: Your Console.WriteLine() is outside the foreach loop so it will only have the value of the last element in the array, which is false. If you move the Console.WriteLine() inside the foreach then you should get the full sequence printed with the right trues and falses....

Comment: your code is not evaluate. what purpose serve of LOOP , use much only of microsoft LINQ for loop omit.

Answer (score 1):

The 7th value is `true`, but then the 8th value is `false`, overwriting the `true` value in `myIsShouldBeTrue`

You could OR each value, so if a `true` exists, it will be persisted:

```
foreach (bool valueBl in myValuesBls)
{
    myIsShouldBeTrue = myIsShouldBeTrue || valueBl;
}
```

Comment: How can I keep it from being overwritten?  I find it pretty odd that I can't keep my value from being destroyed by .net.

Comment: you shouldn't be using a foreach loop if you want to stop before the end of the array is reached

Comment: I find it pretty primitive that .net can't let someone out of a loop.  I'm disappointed now.

Comment: @RagingDave Added some code that will perhaps do what you want.

Comment: @RagingDave It's certainly *possible* to do what you want, you just haven't coded it properly.  There more certainly exist sufficient language features to do exactly what you want.  The simplest way would be `bool areAnyTrue = myValuesBls.Any(b => b);`  (You could do it with a loop too, if you wanted.)  Note you didn't ask in your question to provide code that returned a boolean indicating if any of the values in the array were true, you asked for us to explain why your code does what it does.

Comment: @RagingDave you didn't do anything to exit the loop. .NET is not at fault here. The program does exactly what one would expect.

Answer (score 1):

what happens when you try this?

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
bool[] myValuesBls = new bool[10];

for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
    if (i == 7) {
        myValuesBls[i] = true;
    } else {
        myValuesBls[i] = false;
    }
}

bool myIsShouldBeTrue = false;
foreach (bool valueBl in myValuesBls) {
    myIsShouldBeTrue = valueBl;
    if (myIsShouldBeTrue == true)
        break;
}

Console.WriteLine(myIsShouldBeTrue);
Console.ReadLine();
}
```

What this SHOULD do is exit the FOR LOOP at the point when your value is TRUE.

NOTE: it may not work as i expect it to, as i have converted the code from VB as my VB skills are better

Answer (score 0):

`myIsShouldBeTrue = valueBl[9]` in the end would be `FALSE`
so 
 `Console.WriteLine(myIsShouldBeTrue)` should output `FALSE`!

Comment: Why would I want to limit my array so it always ends with true?

Comment: becouse in loop         foreach (bool valueBl in myValuesBls)
        {
            myIsShouldBeTrue = valueBl;
        }  on the last iteration myIsShouldBeTrue would be equal to valueBl[9] which is equal to FALSE

Answer (score 0):

if you change the contents of the foreach loop to

```
if(valueBl == true)
{
    myIsShouldBeTrue = valueBl;
}
```

then it will output true. but as the others have said, it's a for loop, so console is outputting the LAST value in the array, which is false.

really, if you want your loop to end when a condition is reached within the loop, you should use a while or do/while loop. for loops are really intended for going through the entire array. if you're lazy though, you can also get out of a for loop by sticking a return; in it, but you'll still need a test condition for the return

edit: Java version

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        boolean[] myValuesBls = new boolean[10];

        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (i == 7)
                myValuesBls[i] = true;
            else
                myValuesBls[i] = false;
        }

        boolean myIsShouldBeTrue = false;
        for(boolean valueBl : myValuesBls)
        {
            if(valueBl == true)  // condition
            {
                myIsShouldBeTrue = valueBl;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(myIsShouldBeTrue);
    }
```

this will output true.

Comment: I tried your solution:  if (valueBL == true) return;  I now get no output at all.

Comment: @RagingDave what language? c#? i'm editing my answer to demonstrate the java version, i haven't coded in c#, but it's very similar

Comment: @RagingDave .NET is not a language. The language in this case is C#.

Answer (score 0):

The loop that you have:

```
bool myIsShouldBeTrue = false;
foreach (bool valueBl in myValuesBls)
{
    myIsShouldBeTrue = valueBl;
}
```

goes through each item in the array, and sets the value of `myIsShouldBeTrue` to be the value of the current item.  The effect of this is that `myIsShouldBeTrue` will always be the last item in the array.

It would appear, based on your comments, that you want to determine if any of the values in the array are true.  There are a number of ways that we can do that.  Sticking most closely with your code we can set `myIsShouldBeTrue` to be the result of `myIsShouldBeTrue` ORed with the current item.  That way the line will read as, "Either I've already found a true value, or this item is true".  The code change is quite simple:

```
bool myIsShouldBeTrue = false;
foreach (bool valueBl in myValuesBls)
{
    myIsShouldBeTrue |= valueBl;
}
```

The `|=` operator sets the value to be the result of that value ORed with the operand.

We could improve this code if we wished.  For starters, there really is no need to continue looping through the collection once we've found an item that's true.  We know the result will be true at that point, so we can quit.  This is called "short circuiting" with respect to boolean operations.

```
bool myIsShouldBeTrue = false;
foreach (bool valueBl in myValuesBls)
{
    if (valueBl)
    {
        myIsShouldBeTrue = true;
        break;//exit the loop
    }
}
```

LINQ is also a fantastic tool that can be leveraged here.  It has operations designed for aggregating a result based on a sequence of data.  In this particular case we want to know if any of the boolean values are true.  We can write this out as:

```
myIsShouldBeTrue = myValuesBls.Any(value => value);
```

If any of the values are true then `myIsShouldBeTrue` will be true.  The end result is code that's not too different from our earlier loop, although it's a bit easier to apply `Any` to somewhat tougher problem, and it does a *great* job of reading just like our requirements.  Once you get used to the syntax it becomes much easier to see exactly what the intent of the author is.